# Why does Google Music Manager refuse to open in 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, music, google, google-musicmanager

I like to upload my music to my Google account and I use Google Music Manager to do this.

When I downloaded the music manager the first time, I wanted to actually download all the music I purchased from Google onto my Ubuntu 12.04 Dell Latitude E6400 32-bit. It worked fine and all the music downloaded.

Now I have ripped some of my old cds and want to upload that content to Google. When I chose Google Music Manager from my applications, it pops up in my tray as running but nothing actually happens. When I click on it and chose options which used to open up the interface to chose which folders you wanted to upload and so forth, nothing happens.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled several times and it still does the same thing. I ran it from command line and I see I am getting the errors below.

I intend on asking this same question in a Google forum but I wanted to ask here since I usually get better answers from the Ubuntu community.

```
t:~$ google-musicmanager

log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (root).

log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly.
```

Comment: See the problem is that I can only start music manager. After that I can do nothing with it. I click options, nothing happens so I cannot select a file or do anything with it. I cannot log out of it. I even tried uninstalling and reinstalling and it has me automatically logged in when I start it back up.

Answer (score 36):

1. Quit google-musicmanager.
2. Delete the directory `~/.config/google-musicmanager`.
3. Start google-musicmanager again. You'll get an initial setup wizard again - this time, choose an empty directory to **upload** music. Then the bug will not be there anymore.

I found this workaround [on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2087385&page=2).

Comment: I want to download music instead of uploading and choosing the folder explicitly doesn't help

Comment: OK, I chose "uploading" with an empty music folder and then I could get to the options and choose download from there

Comment: Great, this helped solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problems, and after deleting `google-music-manager` from `~/.config` it persisted... Until I realized that you have to give Google solid user input on all prompts.

When it asks where to upload from, choose your music folder from the file-tree. Don't just choose the default option. Once I had filled out all boxes and forms, music manager behaves normally, at least in terms of responding to mouse clicks.

I also had to fix a DNS problem, but it's not likely you have that too.

Now if I could only get it to keep downloading my music without quitting halfway through.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading is the only solution that works for me: 
[google-musicmanager 64bit](http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/pool/main/g/google-musicmanager-beta/google-musicmanager-beta_1.0.55.7425-r0_amd64.deb) or 
[google-musicmanager 32bit](http://dl.google.com/linux/musicmanager/deb/pool/main/g/google-musicmanager-beta/google-musicmanager-beta_1.0.55.7425-r0_i386.deb)