# google-musicmanager Couldn't connect to Google Play

Tags: 18.04, google

I've been using Google Music Manager for a while (years?) on Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and suddenly today it can't connect. It asks for my login and password, then my password again with a captcha, then an MFA code, then it says "Couldn't connect to Google Play - Check your internet connection and try again" (screenshot below). The "Retry" button has no noticeable effect. I can reach other sites and services on the Internet just fine. I don't have any outbound firewall filters configured.

I tried tips from [here](https://support.google.com/googleplaymusic/answer/1144026?hl=en) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/236942) -- no luck.

Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: google music manager displaying google play connection error]

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue as well - I had already installed Google MusicManager at some point, and blew it up when I installed an update.

My solution was to COMPLETELY remove it and its configuration.  First, removing it completely via apt:

`sudo apt-get purge google-musicmanager-beta`

Then, tracked down all remaining files that referenced it and removed them, including within my own profile:

`cd /
find . -iname '*musicmanager*'
rm <anything that was found above>`

Then I reinstalled, and it came up with initial setup dialogs and worked properly.  Note that there have been comments that for people with two-factor auth using the feature to just click "Yes" on the phone doesn't work - I had it send me a text message with an auth code instead and it authenticated just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Mine started working after I waited a few days. I supposed Google was having issues on their end. If it breaks again I'll try your method. If someone else can verify it as a fix I'll accept it.

Comment: Seems like a database error. Removing `~/.config/google-musicmanager/` and reinstalling did help. Thank you!

Comment: If you use Two-Factor Auth, choose sending code via SMS, it works.

Comment: I tried fixing by changing Two-Factor Auth to get SMS code instead and it still failed to connect.  Going to try re-install.